# Prove $\sigma :\mathbb{F}^{2} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{FP}^{2};\, (x,y) \mapsto (x:y:1)$ is a homeomorphism onto its image

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am trying to prove that the maps that embeds $\mathbb{F}^{2}$ into $\mathbb{FP}^{2}$ is indeed a homeomorphism on to its image, however I am struggling to understand how I can show the function and its inverse are continuous especially since were are dealing with ratios of points in the co-domain.

Comment: What topologies are you considering? Also, you mean that it is a homeomorphism with the image, right? It is not a bijective map.

Comment: @CaptainLama $\mathbb{F}^{2}$ is a general field while $\mathbb{FP}^{2}$ is the projective space and yes I do mean with the image. I don't have much experience in topology so I'm not sure of the specifics but I saw the statement $\mathbb{F}^{2}$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{FP}^{2}$ via $(x,y) \rightarrow (x:y:1)$ which I am trying to understand and prove.

Comment: Well, the first thing you should do is try to understand what are the topologies involved, if you want the embedding to be topological. Here you should probably check what the Zariski topology is.